# Is mutex mandatory to access extern variable from a different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, mutex

I am developing an application in Qt/C++. At some point, there are two threads : one is the UI thread and the other one is the background thread. I have to do some operation from the background thread based on the value of an extern variable which is type of `bool`. I am setting this value by clicking a button on UI.

**header.cpp**

```
extern bool globalVar;
```

**mainWindow.cpp**

```
//main ui thread on button click
setVale(bool val){
 globalVar = val;
}
```

**backgroundThread.cpp**

```
 while(1){
  if(globalVar)
    //do some operation
  else
    //do some other operation
  }
```

Here, writing to `globalVar` happens only when the user clicks the button whereas reading happens continuously.

So my question is :

1. In a situation like the one above, is mutex mandatory?
2. If read and write happens at the same time, does this cause the application to crash?
3. If read and write happens at same time, is `globalVar` going to have some value other than `true` or `false`?
4. Finally, does the OS provide any kind of locking mechanism to prevent the read/write operation to access a memory location at the same time by a different thread?

Comment: Classic data race. Some form of synchronization (not neccessarily `std::mutex`) is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In situation like above does mutex is necessary?

A mutex is one tool that will work. What you actually need are three things:

1. a means of ensuring an atomic update (a bool will give you this as it's mandated to be an integral type by the standard)
2. a means of ensuring that the effects of a write made by one thread is actually visible in the other thread. This may sound counter-intuitive but the c++ memory model is single-threaded and optimisations (software and hardware) do not need to consider cross-thread communication, and...
3. a means of preventing the compiler (and CPU!!) from re-ordering the reads and writes.

The answer to the implied question is 'yes'. You will need something at does all of these things (see below)

> If read and write happend at the same time does this cause to crash the application?

not when it's a bool, but the program won't behave as you expect. In fact, because the program is now exhibiting undefined behaviour you can no longer reason about its behaviour at all.

> If read and write happens at same time, is globalVar going to have some value other thantrue or false?

not in this case because it's an intrinsic (atomic) type.

> And is it going to happen the access(read/write) of a memory location at same time by different thread, does OS providing any kind of locking mechanism to prevent it?

Not unless you specify one.

Your options are:

- `std::atomic<bool>`
- `std::mutex`
- `std::atomic_signal_fence`

Comment: Actually I don't want to implement complex method to solve this problem, similar thing I have to implement 3-4 places in my source code, if I follow mutex method then on each place I have to implement different mutex, readwrite functions etc, this will make my source code more complex. I   think better I use atomic varibale but I don't have c++11 support at the moment, and as I am using Qt, and I can see Qt has it's own AtomicInteger class http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qatomicinteger.html#details but not sure it's thread safe.

Comment: I can probably manage (on x86) to create bool which will not be written atomicaly. Not sure, but I see how I can try.

Comment: @SergeyA - bring it :)

Comment: @CodeDezk I'm no expert in QT but I'm pretty sure if it's called AtomicXXX the library writers will have taken care that it is atomic and does emit the correct fences.

Comment: @SergeyA if your custom bool was a bit in a bitfield then it won't be atomic. If it's a native type the standard guarantees that it must be modifiable without touching the next nearest variable. That's not a guarantee of atomicity but it's close.

Comment: @RichardHodges, standard doesn't say anything about atomicity of updates of built-in types (unless they are `std::atomic`). And on Intel unaligned writes are not atomic.

Comment: @SergeyA I'll look it up. the c++ memory model guarantees that every discrete variable is updatable without the write touching another. If that means the compiler must insert padding, then it will.

Comment: @RichardHodges, I believe, we are talking about different things. Yes, updates to distinct objects are guaranteed to be independent of any other updates. By atomicity I meant that one thread can update boolean variable from false to false, and another thread reading the same boolean variable will read true - and this can happen.

Comment: @SergeyA I concur, and hope that I have covered this in my answer, citing it as the reason for needing a fence. I'll check my wording to see if i can make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is just a single plain bool, I'd say a mutex is overkill, you should just go for an atomic integer instead. An atomic will read and write in a single CPU clock so no worries there, and it will be lock free, which is always better if possible.

If it is something more complex, then by all means go for a mutex.

It won't crash from that alone, but you can get data corruption, which may crash the application.

The system will not manage that stuff for you, you do it manually, just make sure all access to the data goes through the mutex.

Edit:

Since you specify a number of times that you don't want a complex solution, you may opt for simply using a mutex instead of the bool. There is no need to protect the bool with a mutex, since you can use the mutex as a bool, and yes, you could go with an atomic, but that's what the mutex already does (plus some extra functionality in the case of recursive mutexes).

It also matters what is your exact workload, since your example doesn't make a lot of sense in practice. It would be helpful to know what those `some operation`s are.

So in your ui thread you could simply `val ? mutex.lock() : mutex.unlock()`, and in your secondary thread you could use `if (mutex.tryLock()) doStuff; mutex.unlock(); else doOtherStuff;`. Now if the operation in the secondary thread takes too long and you happen to be changing the lock in the main thread, that will block the main thread until the secondary thread unlocks. You could use `tryLock(timeout)` in the main thread, depending on what you prefer, `lock()` will block until success, while `tryLock(timeout)` will prevent blocking but the lock may fail. Also, take care not to unlock from a thread other than the one you locked with, and not to unlock an already unlocked mutex.

Depending on what you are actually doing, maybe an asynchronous event driven approach would be more appropriate. Do you really need that `while(1)`? How frequently do you perform those operations?

Comment: I think you should specify why the current code is wrong and why *atomic* fix it.

Comment: Add clarification for data race, and replace atomic int with atomic bool, and it will be a good answer.

Comment: @ddriver Yes it's necessary, in my original code I continuously retrieving data(frame) from a video file using `ffmpeg` and doing some operation on the frame.

Comment: @CodeDezk are you playing those frames or processing them offline?

Comment: Yes after processing I am displaying it on a Window.

Comment: @CodeDezk - for the purpose of playback you don't need a blocking loop, you need an event/timer driven solution, for example for 30 FPS you need it once every 33 milliseconds, which will be a lot easier on your CPU than `while(1)` - and you can avoid the need for manual synchronization too. You are simply throwing the wrong tools at this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The loop

```
while(1){
   if(globalVar)
      //do some operation
   else
      //do some other operation
}
```

is [*busy waiting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), which is extremely wasteful. Thus, you're probably better off with some classic synchronization that will wake the background thread (mostly) when there is something to be done. You should consider adapting [this example of `std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Say you start with:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;
```

Your worker thread can then be something like this:

```
void worker_thread()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // Wait until main() sends data
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});

        ready = false;

        lk.unlock();
}
```

The notifying thread should do something like this:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
    ready = true;
}
cv.notify_one();
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to implement complex method to solve this problem, similar thing I have to implement 3-4 places in my source code, if I follow mutex method then on each place I have to implement different mutex, readwrite functions etc, this will make my source code more complex. I think better I use atomic varibale but I don't have c++11 support at the moment, and as I am using Qt, and I can see Qt has it's own AtomicInteger class doc.qt.io/qt-5/qatomicinteger.html#details but not sure it's thread safe.

Comment: @CodeDezk I don't think you can reasonably use busy waiting.

Comment: The problem with the code is not busy waiting, which might be approriate or not, but a data race.

Comment: SergeyA's comment is a strawman: the answer does not state that there is no data race problem in the question, and the solution does not leave a data race. Of the various ways to solve the data race, however, it is better to show alternatives to busy waiting, which, in general, is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically speaking, as long as you use an integer type (not `bool`), make it `volatile`, and keep inside of its own cache line by properly aligning its storage, you don't need to do anything special at all.

> In situation like above does mutex is necessary?

Only if you want to keep the value of the variable synchronized with other state.

> If read and write happed at the same time does this cause to crash the application?

According to C++ standard, it's undefined behavior. So anything can happen: e.g. your application might not crash, but its state might be subtly corrupted. In real life, though, compilers often offer some sane implementation defined behavior and you're fine unless your platform is really weird. Anything commonplace, like 32 and 64 bit intel, PPC and ARM will be fine.

> If read and write happens at same time, is globalVar going to have some value other thantrue or false?

`globalVar` can only have these two values, so it makes no sense to speak of any other values unless you're talking about its binary representation. Yes, it could happen that the binary representation is incorrect and not what the compiler would expect. That's why you shouldn't use a `bool` but a `uint8_t` instead.

I wouldn't love to see such flag in a code review, but if a `uint8_t` flag is the simplest solution to whatever problem you're solving, I say go for it. The `if (globalVar)` test will treat zero as `false`, and anything else as `true`, so temporary "gibberish" is OK and won't have any odd effects in practice. According to the standard, you'll be facing undefined behavior, of course.

> And is it going to happen the access(read/write) of a memory location at same time by different thread, does OS providing any kind of locking mechanism to prevent it?

It's not the OS's job to do that.

Speaking of practice, though: on any reasonable platform, the use of a `std::atomic_bool` will have no overhead over the use of a naked `uint8_t`, so just use that and be done.